# enable to send mail via PhpMailer?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have configure and install composer in my project,i also require the `autoload.php` file into my file to send mail.my all login details are also correct but while running the application i m getting `SMTP ERROR: Password command failed`i have included detailed error below.please help me to sort out this problem

```
            <?php
            require_once 'vendor/vendor/autoload.php';
            $m = new PHPMailer;

            $m->isSMTP();
            $m->SMTPAuth = true;
            $m->SMTPDebug = 2;
            $m->Host= 'smtp.gmail.com';
            $m->Username = 'suhasgawde10@gmail.com';
            $m->Password = '*************';

            $m->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
            $m->Port = 465;

            $m->From = 'suhasgawde10@gmail.com';
            $m->FromName = 'Suhas Gawde';
            $m->addReplyTo('suhasgawde10@gmail.com','Reply address');
            $m->addAddress('suhasgawde10@gmail.com','Suhas Gawde');

            $m->Subject = "Here is the subject";
            $m->Body = 'this is mailed send throught php mailer';
            $m->AltBody= 'this is mailed send throught php mailer';

            if(!$m->send()){
                echo "Mailer Error: " . $m->ErrorInfo;
            }
            else{
                echo 'success';
            }
            ?>
```

Error while running this file :

```
          2015-06-25 10:48:42   SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 mx.google.com ESMTP
          si7sm29610201pbc.54 - gsmtp 2015-06-25 10:48:42   CLIENT -> 
          SERVER: EHLO localhost 2015-06-25 10:48:43    SERVER -> CLIENT: 
          250-mx.google.com at your service, [59.182.41.18] 250-SIZE 
          35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-            
          CLIENTTOKEN XOAUTH 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-
          CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 2015-06-25 10:48:43 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH
          LOGIN 2015-06-25 10:48:43 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 2015-
          06-25 10:48:43    CLIENT -> SERVER:     
          c3VoYXNnYXdkZTEwQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ== 2015-06-25 
          10:48:44  SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 2015-06-25 10:48:44  
         CLIENT -> SERVER: Z2FuYXBhdGlAMTAwOA== 2015-06-25 10:48:44 SERVER -
          > CLIENT: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-
          5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 
          https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 si7sm29610201pbc.54 - 
          gsmtp 2015-06-25 10:48:44 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 
          534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then 
          try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14
          https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 si7sm29610201pbc.54 - 
          gsmtp 2015-06-25 10:48:44 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. 
          2015-06-25 10:48:44   CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 2015-06-25 10:48:45  
          SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection si7sm29610201pbc.54 
          - gsmtp 2015-06-25 10:48:45   SMTP connect() failed. 
          https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Mailer 
          Error: SMTP connect() failed. 
          https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Comment: Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: How about you help yourself first by reading the docs linked to in the error message?

Answer (score 0):

While using `$m->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';` openssl extension should be enabled

In php.ini file remove semicolon from this line  `;extension=php_openssl.dll` (if available)

Or

you can try 'tls' for SMTPSecure

```
$m->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$m->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$m->Port = 587;
```

Check with this setting hope it will help

Comment: i tried both options which are suggested by you @keviveks but not working please suggest me any other option :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using "tls" for SMTPSecure and 587 for Port.

Also if you already remove the semicolon from the file in php.ini like kevikeks suggested, and it still does not work.

Try this:
Make sure your details are correct for $m->Username and $m->Password.
Then go to your google account under setting/security/lesssecureapps and turn on access for less secure apps. Now run the .php file and see if you get an email.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Your code looks right to me, but make sure this "require_once 'vendor/vendor/autoload.php';" included the right path to the .php file name PHPMailerAutoload.php. Also the Username and Password should be your real google account details.